# What is the point of an LC Circuit in a Tesla Coil?

Tags: transformer, passive-networks, tesla-coil

In a Tesla Coil, why does the Secondary circuit need the high frequency of the Primary LC Circuit? How come it doesn't work with the frequency of mains power? I'm aware that the LC Circuit resonates at much higher frequencies than mains power, but considering the ratio of turns between the primary and secondary coil, and a high input voltage, shouldn't that be able to create an output voltage high enough to generate archs? In other words, why can't we just have a few transformers in series stepping up the voltage? Or is that not as efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tesla Coil demonstrates the physics of **high frequency** and high voltage (for example, it jumps sparks from a single conductor, with the far end of the spark hanging in empty air.)  A Tesla Coil is the same as a high-power radio transmitter without an antenna.

But a 60Hz high-voltage transformer is not a Tesla Coil.  It doesn't demonstrate any high-frequency physics.  It can only jump sparks between two conductors.  It's just AC power supply with few-hundred kilovolts output (also called an "X-ray transformer," and used to drive old pre-1980s x-ray machines.)

Also, what if you have a Tesla Coil with no secondary coil?  Just the primary circuit, spark gap, power supply, etc.?   That's called a high-frequency induction heater.  In early pre-tube days of RF power the induction heaters used spark gaps.  Place metal objects within the primary coil, and they are heated by high-frequency induced currents.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the entire theory of operation behind how a Tesla coil works.

The turns ratio does not have much of an effect on the output voltage. A common ratio of primary windings to secondary windings is 1:100, but you get WAY more than 100x the input voltage due to *resonant rise*. When two tuned circuits in close proximity have the same resonant frequency, energy transfer between them is very efficient and you get constructive interference (that is, waveforms add to waveforms). This resonance is how you get the increase in voltage amplitude. In theory it would be possible to build a secondary resonant circuit that resonates at mains frequency but this would require a huge amount of inductance and capacitance and is extremely impractical and unrealistic.

I suggest reading up on how Tesla coils actually work. It is clear you do not have even a slight understanding of how they operate, and it would greatly benefit you to learn.

Comment: You're saying that there is an increase in voltage due to constructive interference. So, like adding a bunch of sine waves, I achieve a higher amplitude. And shall I assume resistance within the wire plays no major role between each cycle of resonance during this rise because the frequency is so high?

Comment: DC resistance within the wire does play a role but it is overwhelmed by the voltage on the secondary and you probably wouldn't notice much of a difference. There is, however, a reason why you do not use finer wire than necessary because that does add significant resistance and may become more of a factor.